# Modify paths in git history from src/ to src/main/java

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I basically need to modify paths in whole git history from `src/...` into `src/main/java/...` fixing the directory structure to Maven rules.

I am trying to find a working sample of `git filter-branch --tree-filter` that would do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you *really* sure you want to rewrite history, not just rename the directory in one commit? Rewriting the complete history is looking for troubles...

Comment: Yes I am. We are migrating from Mercurial into Git. So noone is already using migrated git repository and I only have the chance to do such changes right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mv src src_old && mkdir -p src/main && mv src_old src/main/java' -- --all
```

Comment: `--index-filter` would be more adapted here: no need to checkout each revision, just `git mv` the directory in the index. Both work, but `--index-filter` is faster.

Comment: I thought about it, but does that actually work? `git mv` has no `--cached` option like `git rm` has.

Comment: Can you add an example with --index-filter please?

Comment: No, there is none. It does not work as I said. `git mv` needs a working tree to work. And even if it would work in a cached only mode, you would need a "create directory" command that works only on the index too, also with `git mv` you cannot move something to a non-existent place. It simply does not work, I just tried it. @Matthieu Moy if you think it works please give an example, otherwise please delete your comment as it is misleading, especially as the up-vote signals it might be correct.

Comment: Indeed, short of a `git mv --cached`, there's no simple way to use `--index-filter`. One could probably hack something with `git update-index`, but that would probably be overkill.